# Raspberry pi golang doesn't run , uuid package problem

Tags: go, go-modules

I worked with GO on raspberry Pi a month ago without any problem. Today I started my old script, first, it works like before, but suddenly something went wrong, so I reinstall GO and Gobot, But now I cant run my scripts anymore and I have this error message when i use  **go run .** command

```
'# github.com/gobuffalo/uuid
/home/pi/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gobuffalo/uuid@v2.0.5+incompatible/generator.go:32:13: undefined: uuid.NewV2
/home/pi/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gobuffalo/uuid@v2.0.5+incompatible/uuid.go:41:7: undefined: uuid.V2
```

Comment: What happens if you run `go build` in the directory which contains your `go.mod` file?

Comment: command execute normally

Comment: So, as a result you should now have an executable image file which you can just execute by running `./that_file`. Does this work? Basically, I'm leading you to understanding that Go (at least _stock_ implementations of Go) is not a scripting language, and one should never ever use `go run` for anything serious. Go programs are intended to be built and then executed via the binary created by the building process. (Well, I mean, it's sort of OK for usage by experts in some limited cases but please do not use it for production purposes).

Comment: @kostix @kostix not is doesn't work.. VS code  send these messages                                                                     
( package: command not found _____ syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
______`import (' )

Comment: Exploiting my "mad psychic debugging skillz", I could guess you have somehow told vscode to _execute one of your source code files via a shell:_ so that vscode calls something like `/bin/sh /path/to/that/file`. Unix shells treat their non-option arguments as names of files to interpret as shell scripts. Since any Go source code file begins with the package declaration, that's what the shell reads and tries to interpret as a script; there's no command/program named "package" known to the shell, and it fails.

Comment: …and that is not what I asked your about. Could you please follow some HOWTO on how to prepare VSCode work with Go projects—that is, how to _build_ a Go project using VSCode and then run it? (I'm not using VSCode, so I have nothing to offer as an immediate advice on this, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just by tapping this command line :

**go get gobot.io/x/gobot@dev**